# Extracting different length of numbers (latitude and longitude) from unstructured text file with R

Tags: r, regex, string, latitude-longitude

I want to extract differents latitudes and longitudes from  from unstructured text file. The coordinates can take these forms : 
"0.41566" ; "-0.41566" ; "21.36584785" ; "100.2457

This syntax works only for numbers like that 120.564874

```
library(stringr) 
lat <- c("([0-9]{3}) [.] ([0-9]{6})")
essailat<-str_extract_all(essai,lat, simplify=F)
```

But As I said, I would like to extract all the other formats presented above.

```
library(stringr) 
lat <- c("([0-9]{1}) [.] ([0-9]{4})", "([0-9]{3}) [.] ([0-9]{6})")
essailat<-str_extract_all(essai,lat, simplify=F)
```

But it does not seems to work. Plus sometimes, my lat is a negative number (`-0.41567`) so I would like to specify that it extract as well the negative sign

Thank you in advance for your help.

PS: this is what I meant to specify a unstructured file and as lon and lat works by pair I can extract first all the lat with a certain type of format but all of them at once respecting the order.

THANK YOU in advance for your help !

Sample input:

```
cacacacacacaacacacacacaacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacac"latitude":"900.252578";cacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccccacacacacaca"longitude":"0.997754"cacacacacacaacacacacacaacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacac"latitude":"0.252578";cacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccccacacacacaca"longitude":"-0.997754"cacacacacacaacacacacacaacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacac"latitude":"0.252578";cacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccccacacacacaca"longitude":"0.997754"cacacacacacaacacacacacaacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacac"latitude":"0.252578";cacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccccacacacacaca"longitude":"0.997754"cacacacacacaacacacacacaacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacac"latitude":"-0.252578";cacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccccacacacacaca"longitude":"0.997754"cacacacacacaacacacacacaacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacac"latitude":"0.252578";cacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccccacacacacaca"longitude":"-0.997754"cacacacacacaacacacacacaacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacac"latitude":"0.252578";cacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccccacacacacaca"longitude":"0.997754"cacacacacacaacacacacacaacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacac"latitude":"0.252578";cacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccccacacacacaca"longitude":"0.997754"cacacacacacaacacacacacaacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacac"latitude":"0.252578";cacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccccacacacacaca"longitude":"0.997754"cacacacacacaacacacacacaacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following fix:

```
> library(stringr)
> lat <- "-?[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+"
> s <- "cacacacacacaacacacacacaacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacac\"latitude\":\"900.252578\";cacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccccacacacacaca\"longitude\":\"0.997754\"cacacacacacaacacacacacaacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacac\"latitude\":\"0.252578\";cacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccccacacacacaca\"longitude\":\"-0.997754\"cacacacacacaacacacacacaacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacac\"latitude\":\"0.252578\";cacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccccacacacacaca\"longitude\":\"0.997754\"cacacacacacaacacacacacaacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacac\"latitude\":\"0.252578\";cacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccccacacacacaca\"longitude\":\"0.997754\"cacacacacacaacacacacacaacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacac\"latitude\":\"-0.252578\";cacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccccacacacacaca\"longitude\":\"0.997754\"cacacacacacaacacacacacaacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacac\"latitude\":\"0.252578\";cacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccccacacacacaca\"longitude\":\"-0.997754\"cacacacacacaacacacacacaacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacac\"latitude\":\"0.252578\";cacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccccacacacacaca\"longitude\":\"0.997754\"cacacacacacaacacacacacaacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacac\"latitude\":\"0.252578\";cacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccccacacacacaca\"longitude\":\"0.997754\"cacacacacacaacacacacacaacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacac\"latitude\":\"0.252578\";cacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacaccccacacacacaca\"longitude\":\"0.997754\"cacacacacacaacacacacacaacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacacac"
> essailat<-str_extract_all(s,lat)
> essailat
[[1]]
 [1] "900.252578" "0.997754"   "0.252578"   "-0.997754"  "0.252578"   "0.997754"   "0.252578"   "0.997754"  
 [9] "-0.252578"  "0.997754"   "0.252578"   "-0.997754"  "0.252578"   "0.997754"   "0.252578"   "0.997754"  
[17] "0.252578"   "0.997754"
```

The `-?[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+` regex will match an optional `-`, then 1+ digits, a literal `.`, and again 1+ digits.

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/O7WTRt/1).